# The sum seems to be 40 but how

Tags: php, math

I am trying to explore php and to learn it a little bit but when i tried this

```
    $n=2;
    $a=5;
    $x=3;
    $s=0;
    $i;
    for($i=1; $i<=($n+2);$i++)
    $s=$s+(2*$i+$a);

   //$g=3*$x+4*$s;
   echo "$s";
```

the result seems to be 40, and when i calculate it by myself the sum of s is 13
I know this is simple but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: How are you getting 13? At no point is it ever 13. 1st iteration: `7 = 0+(2*1+5)`, 2nd: `16 = 7+(2*2+5)`, 3rd: `27 = 16+(2*3+5)`, 4th: `40 = 27+(2*4+5)`.

Comment: Okay s=0+(2*4+5) = 0+(8+5) = 0+13 = 13

Comment: That's not what you coded. You may want to rethink your code.

Comment: And I just did and understand it. good work by all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple math, the php code does exactly what it looks like it does. Am I missing something?

loop 1:

```
    $i = 1
    $s = 0 + (2*1 + 5) = 7
```

loop 2:

```
    $i = 2
    $s = 7 + (2*2 + 5) = 7 + 4 + 5 = 16
```

loop 3:

```
    $i = 3
    $s = 16 + (2*3 + 5) = 16 + 6 + 5 = 27
```

loop 4:

```
    $i = 4
    $s = 27 + (2*4 + 5) = 27 + 8 + 5 = 40
```

Answer (score 1):

its very simple, since i<=($n+2) the total iterations will be 4.
for first iteration,

```
$i=1 the value of s = 0+(2*1+5) = 7
$i=2 now s = 7+(2*2+5) = 16
$i=3 now s = 16+(2*3+5) = 27
$i=4 now s = 27+(2*4+5) = 40
```

Hope this explains.

Answer (score 0):

N=2;
A=5;
X=3;
S=0;

```
for
  I=1 => S (0) = 0 + (2*1+5) = 7

  I=2 => S (7) = 7 + (2*2+5) = 16

  I=3 => S (16) =  16 + (2*3+5) = 27

  I=4 => S (27) = 27 (2*4+5) = 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudo code:

```
n = 2
a = 5
s = 0

for ( i in { 1...4 } ) {

    s = s + ( ( 2 * i ) + 5 )
}
```

So we have

```
s =  0 + ( ( 2 * 1 ) + 5 ) =  0 +  7 = 7
s =  7 + ( ( 2 * 2 ) + 5 ) =  7 +  9 = 16
s = 16 + ( ( 2 * 3 ) + 5 ) = 16 + 11 = 27
s = 27 + ( ( 2 * 4 ) + 5 ) = 27 + 13 = 40
```

Comment: hmmm, so the S is getting the value every time since the i equals to 4. am I right ?

Comment: i think you mean till, not since

Comment: I will count from 1, to 4, for each of the four loops through. Each time you will be reassigning the value of S, using the previous value.

Comment: @inarilo yes i mean 'till' , am not a native english speaker but I keep learning, and I couldnt remember the word 'till' when I was writing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple math. s is the sum of for i from 1 to n+2 of 2i+a. This is equal to the twice sum of i plus the sum of a. The latter is clearly worth (n+2)a. The former is twice the sum of integers from 1 to n+2, i.e. 2 * (n+2)(n+3)/2. The total is thus (n+2)(n+3) + (n+2)a = (n+2)(n+3+a) = (2+2)*(2+3+5) = 4*10 = 40. (Side effect: no need to have an explicit loop, just implement the above formula.)